# How to automate modify security groups inbound rules in aws ec2 using java sdk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am trying to find the documentation to update aws ec2 security groups using aws java sdk since 2 days, I am able to find the documentation for creating and deleting the security groups using aws java sdk, but not able to find the same for adding,removing,updating the security group inbound rules using java sdk, if anyone can give me the link to the documentation, or any working sample code in java, it will be really helpful to me.

Comment: What documentation are you looking at, that you can find security group modification, but not security group rule modification? Try searching on this page: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you found the solution to your question since it was posted a month ago.
I am currently working on the same thing and I found that using **AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest** allows you to update already existing Security Groups instead of creating new ones every time.

```
IpRange ipRange = IpRange.builder()
                .cidrIp("0.0.0.0/0").build();

            IpPermission ipPerm = IpPermission.builder()
                .ipProtocol("tcp")
                .toPort(22)
                .fromPort(22)
                .ipRanges(ipRange)
                .build();

            AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest authRequest =
                AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.builder()
                        .groupName(YOUR_GROUP_NAME) // can also use .groupId
                        .ipPermissions(ipPerm)
                        .build();

            ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(authRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just worked through this problem for a project I'm working on.  I found this way harder than it needed to be.  One would think you could just get the rule via [describe-security-groups](https://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html), modify it, and [AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html).  I ended having to get the [Security Group Rule ID](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/easily-manage-security-group-rules-with-the-new-security-group-rule-id/) to remove the rule first, then re-add it.  Here's some working code.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UpdateSecurityGroup {

   private static final String REPORTING_GROUP_ID = "sg-0";


   @PreAuthorize(REPORTING)
   public void updateRule(String tagName, String newSourceIp) {
       final Ec2Client ec2Client = Ec2Client.builder()
                                    .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create("so"))
                                    .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder().build())
                                    .region(Region.AWS_ISO_GLOBAL)
                                    .build();

       updateSecurityGroupEntryByDescription(ec2Client, tagName, newSourceIp);
       ec2Client.close();
   }


   private void updateSecurityGroupEntryByDescription(Ec2Client ec2Client, String tagName, String newSourceIp) {

       try (ec2Client) {
           try {
               final String securityGroupRuleId = findSecurityGroupById(ec2Client, tagName);
               final RevokeSecurityGroupIngressRequest ingressRequest = RevokeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.builder()
                       .groupId(REPORTING_GROUP_ID)
                       .securityGroupRuleIds(securityGroupRuleId)
                       .build();

               ec2Client.revokeSecurityGroupIngress(ingressRequest);

           } catch (Exception ignored) {
               // rule may not be set yet.
           }


           final TagSpecification name = TagSpecification.builder()
                                        .tags(Tag.builder()
                                                .key("Name").value(tagName)
                                                .build())
                                        .resourceType("security-group-rule")
                                        .build();

           final IpPermission build = IpPermission.builder()
                                        .ipProtocol("tcp")
                                        .toPort(443)
                                        .fromPort(443)
                                        .ipRanges(IpRange.builder()
                                                .cidrIp(newSourceIp+"/32")
                                                .build())
                                        .build();

            AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressResponse response = ec2Client.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(
                AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest.builder()
                        .groupId(REPORTING_GROUP_ID)
                        .ipPermissions(build)
                        .tagSpecifications(name)
                        .build());

           log.info("Inbound rule updated successfully: " + response);
       }
   }


   private String findSecurityGroupById(Ec2Client ec2, String tagName) {
        return ec2.describeSecurityGroupRules(
            DescribeSecurityGroupRulesRequest.builder()
                    .filters(Filter.builder()
                            .name("group-id").values(REPORTING_GROUP_ID)
                            .name("tag:Name").values(tagName)
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .securityGroupRules().get(0)
            .securityGroupRuleId();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngressRequest authRequest = UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngressRequest.builder()
                                                         .groupName("default")
                                                         .ipPermissions(ipPerm)
                                                         .build();
UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngressResponse updateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress = ec2.updateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress(authRequest);
```

It works for me